# how to get USB harddisk physical serial number ,vendor id ,product id

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to get USB hard disk serial number ,vendor id ,product id without WMI,I found the

USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_ST932042&Prod_***_***_5VJ101RR&Rev_SDM1\222256410122&0

the serial number is 5VJ101RR but it show in the product id which is wrong,
how can i get the correct USB disk vendor id,product id, serial number
My develop environment is visual c++ 2008

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it is guaranteed that this information is available on all hard-drive devices and if it is, it isn't probably reliable enough. I don't know why you want this for, but it is often used as a first approach for unicity and licensing issues, and it really *should not*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get VID and PID would be to load the devices INI file from %WINDOWS%\System32, I think that is where the INIs are usually copied.  If you know the name of the INI file then it is trivial.  If you are looking for a programmatic method, you can enumerate the USB bus using the Win32 Setup API.

If you have installed the Wnidows Driver Kit on your machine, take a look at the [USBVIEW sample application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It demonstrates how you can enumerate the USB bus and get a list of all devices including their PID and VID.

To get the serial number, look at the [GetVolumeInformation() system call](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139547).

Comment: thanks for your reply ,sorry using GetVolumeInformation() API, This function returns the volume serial number that the operating system assigns when a hard disk is formatted.So when this USB hard drive is formatted ,the serial number is chanage